# pthreads lock recovery

Tags: c, pthreads, freebsd

I am working on a multi-threaded network server application.  At the moment, I am having issues with lock recovery.  If a thread dies unexpectedly while it is holding a lock, say a mutex, rwlock, spinlock, etc..., is it possible to recover the lock from a different thread without having to go into the lock struct itself and manually disassociate the owner from the lock.  I would like to not have to go to this extreme to clear it as this will make the code non-portable.  I have attempted to force a lock owner change by doing a pthread_kill on the offending thread and looking at the return code.  But even using a mutex type attribute of PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK, I still cannot gain control of the mutex from another thread if the locking thread has quit.  This can be a problem if some internal table is being updated when the thread bails out as it will eventually cause the entire server application to halt.

I have used Google extensively and I'm getting conflicting information, even on here.  Any suggestions or ideas that I can explore?

This is on FreeBSD 9.3 using clang-llvm compiler.

Comment: Perhpas the best strategy is to *not* allow the thread to die while holding a lock.

Comment: Threds cannot die unexpectedly. Only whole processes can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For mutexes which are shared between *processes* (`PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`) you can set them `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST`... but you are stuck with the problem that the state protected by the mutex may be invalid -- depending on the application.

For mutexes which are not shared between processes, there is no standard notion of "robustness", because a thread cannot spontaneously die on its own -- a thread will run until either it is cancelled, it exits or the process exits or dies.

You can use:

```
  void pthread_cleanup_push(void (*routine)(void*), void *arg);
  void pthread_cleanup_pop(int execute);
```

to arrange for a mutex to be released if the thread is cancelled or exits while holding the mutex -- something like:

```
  pthread_mutex_lock(&foo) ;      // as now
  pthread_cleanup_push(pthread_mutex_unlock, &foo) ;  // extra step

  ....

  pthread_cleanup_pop(true) ;     // replacing the pthread_mutex_unlock()
```

HOWEVER: you **still** need to think very carefully about what state the data protected by the mutex is in when the thread is cancelled or exits !!

You may be much better off examining why the thread needs this, and perhaps sort out any error/exception handling to pass the error/exception up and out of the critical section (leaving the critical section cleanly).

Comment: Your second paragraph is the key to what I needed to know.  Updates to critical data I try to make as atomic as possible.  It either updates it all at once or not at all is what I'm striving for so the lock is held for the shortest amount of time.  So all I need to do is make sure that any memory that the thread allocates gets freed, correct?

Comment: Ummm... yes, freeing malloc'ed memory is generally a Good Thing, but a thread doesn't (necessarily) need to be the one to free everything *it* has malloc'ed.  If you are only holding the mutex for the shortest time possible, that's also generally a Good Thing... but I'm now puzzled about your original question about needing to force-free a mutex :-(

Comment: The idea was that if the thread aborted while holding the lock for whatever reason, such as a programming error or bad data, then how does one recover the lock it held?  After reviewing the design, I found several areas that needs improvement.  The critical section routines went something like this:  perform all preparatory processing first, get lock, update, release lock.  This way the update is as close to being atomic as possible.